# Deploying web application: How to make just one page secure (https)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, https, web-hosting, web-deployment

I am a new to web deployment and I am deployed a website for testing on `IIS`, the website is non secure (`http`) site but one page should be secure (`https`).

Can anyone suggest me how I can achieve it and it should not warn the user while switching between 'http' and 'https'.

Comment: You can go though this link [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SSL` or *Secure Socket Layer* would be bound to a website through bindings. That is, you can tell IIS to redirect the incoming request traffics to a website, when for example the requested URL would be like `http://domain.com/` or `https://doamin.com`, or `http://200.202.150.200:8080/` or stuff like that.

Therefore, it's not a matter of IIS to set HTTPS only for one page. It's rather how to manage your URLs while redirecting user. In other words, it's a navigational matter.

Comment: I have a small may be silly question  will it requires two application one running on http and another on https? Since http uses 80 port and https uses 443 port by default?

Comment: hi @Saeed, Can you please suggest me how I can redirect to `https://test.co.uk` if request if for 'http://test.co.uk'. Thanks

Comment: URL generation is a general topic. In each framework there are tools and utilities to facilitate the process. For example, in ASP.NET MVC, there is a UrlHelper which generates URLs. The most simple, basic way would be to hard-code the `https://domain.com/targetpath` in your HTTP page.

Comment: @krshekhar, as I said, binding means that you tell IIS to response to the incoming request based on some parameters. Those parameters include `scheme` (http, https, ftp, net.tcp, etc.), `host`, and `port`. Thus you can bind a website (one application) to respond to both `ftp://domain1.com/` and `http://domain2:8080`.

Comment: I believe that hard-coding (`https://domain.com/targetpath`) is not the right way of doing. You have to change your HTML everytime you deploy on different environment. So it's good to use redirection. For Example: Helicon allows to create page specific redirection rules.

Comment: Of course @Hayer, you're right. However, that's simply a matter of architecture which won't regard the OP's question. Like DRY, you have to use some techniques and tools for URL generation and page navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I havent used IIS but I did this recently with Apache.

I did the following:

- Set up a redirect for the page that you wish to secure so it redirects to HTTPS.
- Set up a redirect for every other page to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP
- Ensured static files such as images css and js are not affected by the above rules (These files need to work on both HTTP and HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

If you need this commercially, I would recommend to use Helicon tool to redirect that particular page to `HTTPS`.

Using Helicon tool you can redirect the `HTTP` request to `HTTPS` for any specific page or whole site by writing the Rules.

Comment: no, its not free, that why I said if you need this functionality commercially. But trial version is there. http://www.helicontech.com/download.htm

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7 there is way to define new rules in "URL Rewrite" section for a particular web site. By this you can define a regular expiration and based on that you can redirect any pages which matches the expression to the page which you want. Lets say you are going to redirect http:\x.com\sample.aspx to https:\x.com\sample.aspx. For this do the following steps:

- select your website on IIS
- click URL Rewrite
- Add Rule(s)
- Select Blank rule
- Then define your pattern in this case : lets say ^sample(any page start with sample). you can define any expression as you like.
- in Action section select Redirect in Action type dropdown
- in Redirect URL put https:\x.com\sample.aspx
- save it and restart your website

you can then add any other rules as you want o match your request
And also in some other complex scenarios you can write your own scripts here